# How to subtract numbers in binary

Tags: binary

In this example, it is 5 - 2 which equals 3. How does the computer know that the outcome isn't negative though and why does it not think the answer is 35?

```
 0101 = 5
+1110 = -2
 -----------
10011 = 3
```

What does the 1 and the front of the answer represent?

Comment: Where'd you find your example?

Comment: Is the slide wrong or am I just not understanding this correctly?

Comment: What would happen if you wanted to have a positive number that is e.g 1100? Would that be taken as a negative then? How do you know if the 4th bit represents if positive and negative or if it represents adding 8 or not?

Comment: It depends on the context.  When someone sees `1010` They don't know what the number is until they have the context in which the number is represented, such as 4 bits.  You could have a processor which doesn't have negative numbers, in which case a leading 1 doesn't represent positive or negative, it's just part of the number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The leading one is called overflow.

You are operating on a 4 bit byte if the operation you are using does not move overflow to another byte it will be lost.

```
  0101 =  5
 +1110 = -2
-----------
  0011 =  3
```

Usually processors have a series of flags that can be set by operations in this case the overflow flag will be set to true. As the result exceeds what can be stored in a byte.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you very much. Been spending a long time trying to get my head round this. Would have helped if the lecture notes said that it is a 4 bit byte as it would have made it clearer.